# rabbitmq / amqp direct reply to and return notification

Tags: go, rabbitmq, rpc, amqp

I use rabbitmq for delivering messages from various input-sources (websocket, rest, ...) to my workers. Every worker listens to a bunch of different routing-keys on a shared exchange.

Now it is possible that workerA handles "routeA". When my input-source sends something to routeA, workerA picks it up and consumes it.

But what happens if there is no routeA-"consumer"? In that case I want the input source to "know" that there is no one for that request. And since there is no "rabbit consumer" consuming this message, it is discarded. (sorry if the lingo isn't accurate) As far as I understand the control message (?) handling, that is where `NotifyReturn()` (golang library for amqp) kicks in, so that the publisher can know about the fact, it's message was discarded.

Here is a stripped example of my code. This approach works for me in a simple "just publish this message scenario". I breaks for RPC. 
RPC always triggers the `case returnNotification := <-returnChannel:` case.

My question:

- Am I holding it wrong? / Is this not the way to check the deliverability of a message?

Thanks!

**edit**: Forgot to mention: The error is raised on the "reply". So the request is send, but the reply (send via the "just publish") gets a NO_ROUTE returnNotification

## Just publish

```golang
    // error handling omitted for example code
    tC, _ := rabbitConnection.Channel()
    defer tC.Close()

    tC.Confirm(false)

    var ack = make(chan uint64)
    var nack = make(chan uint64)
    tC.NotifyConfirm(ack, nack)

    returnChannel := make(chan amqp.Return)
    tC.NotifyReturn(returnChannel)

    p := someFunctionGeneratingAPublishing()

    tC.Publish(
        exchange,
        e.GetRoutingKey(),
        true,
        false,
        *p,
    )

    select {
    case returnNotification := <-returnChannel:
        if returnNotification.ReplyCode == amqp.NoRoute {
            return fmt.Errorf("no amqp route for %s", e.GetRoutingKey())
        }

    case <-ack:
        return nil

    case <-nack:
        return fmt.Errorf("basic nack for %s", e.GetRoutingKey())
    }
```

## RPC

```golang
    publishing := someFunctionGeneratingAPublishing()
    publishing.ReplyTo = "amq.rabbitmq.reply-to"

    con := GetConnection()
    directChannel, _ := con.Channel()
    defer directChannel.Close()

    directChannel.Confirm(false)

    var ack = make(chan uint64)
    var nack = make(chan uint64)
    directChannel.NotifyConfirm(ack, nack)

    returnChannel := make(chan amqp.Return)
    directChannel.NotifyReturn(returnChannel)

    // consume direct-reply to pattern queue
    deliveryChan, _ := directChannel.Consume(
        "amq.rabbitmq.reply-to",
        "",
        true,
        false,
        false,
        false,
        nil,
    )


    directChannel.Publish(
        exchange,
        e.GetRoutingKey(),
        true,
        false,
        *publishing,
    )

    select {
    case returnNotification := <-returnChannel:
        if returnNotification.ReplyCode == amqp.NoRoute {
            return fmt.Errorf("no amqp route for %s", e.GetRoutingKey())
        }

    case <-ack:
        return nil

    case <-nack:
        return fmt.Errorf("basic nack for %s", e.GetRoutingKey())
    }
```

Comment: That's not how message queues work. The publisher is expected to fire and forget and assume that sufficient consumers will be made available to keep up with the volume of messages. What you're describing is not a correct usage of message queues.

Comment: @Adrian I understand your premise. But there is the `NotifyReturn()` function, which allows to react to the deliverability of a message. I think my use case is a valid one, as far as I understand amqp. The configuration of the publish (immediate / mandatory) also implies more reliability than "fire and forget".

Comment: The idea is that the consumer can answer to the original message. But the producer should be unaware of "who" answers and be content to get an answer. The whole idea of a message queue is to decouple your application parts as much as possible while still providing two way communication.

Comment: I do not seek to know "who" answered. I simply want to know if the message was routed or not! I really do not understand why this breaks with the idea if a message broker like rabbitmq.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after more wandering in the dark I finaly realized my fundamental error: Not carefully reading the documentation:

> If the RPC server publishes with the mandatory flag set then amq.rabbitmq.reply-to.* is treated as not a queue; i.e. if the server only publishes to this name then the message will be considered "not routed"; a basic.return will be sent if the mandatory flag was set.
>   [RabbitMQ Direct-Reply-To Article](https://www.rabbitmq.com/direct-reply-to.html)

It is by design, that the reply messages, in my configured case, are considered "not routed".